# $ \mu((A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A))=0$ implies $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$. Show that if $ \mu((A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A))=0$ then
>   $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$.

**My attempt**

Firstly, $ \mu((A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A))=0 \implies \mu(A\setminus B)=- \mu(B\setminus A)$ by the finite additivity of the measure (and the disjointness of the sets). It implies that $\mu(A\setminus B)=\mu(B\setminus A)=0$ by the nonnegativeness of the measure. If $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then $\mu(A)=\mu(B)=0$.

**Update**
Define $C=A\cap B$. It holds that
$$C\subseteq A \implies \mu(A\setminus C)+\mu(C)=\mu(A)$$
and
$$C\subseteq B \implies \mu(B\setminus C)+\mu(C)=\mu(B)$$.

Now $A\setminus C=(A\setminus A)\cup (A\setminus B)=A\setminus B$. Similarly, $B\setminus C=B\setminus A$. Both are zero, by the above consideration. Hence $\mu(A)=\mu(B)=\mu(C)$, as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $A = (A\cap B)\ \cup\ (A\setminus B)$, where the union is disjoint. Since $\mu(A\setminus B) = 0$, we have
$$\mu(A) = \mu(A\cap B) + \mu(A\setminus B) = \mu(A\cap B).$$

Similarly,

$$\mu(B) = \mu(A\cap B) + \mu(B\setminus A) = \mu(A\cap B),$$

so $\mu(A) = \mu(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $A$ is the union of the disjoint sets $A \cap B$ and $A \setminus B$

Answer (score 0):

$\mu(A)=\mu(A\cap B)+\mu(A\backslash B)\leq \mu(B)+\mu((A\backslash B)\cup (B\backslash A))=\mu(B)$, where the inequality follows from the monotonicity of measure. Symmetry now implies $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$.